# How to encode javascript in blogspot?

Tags: javascript, encode, html-encode

I have a real estate blogspot website about nha dat go vap at www.nhadatsonnghia.com and I need to encode javascript code like below:

```
var _pEnbRH= "\x65\x76\x61\x6c\x28\x66\x75\x6e\x63\x74\x69\...x7c\x27\x29\x2c\x30\x2c\x7b\x7d\x29\x29\x0a";eval(_pEnbRH);
```

Does anyone know about coding please guide me, I will appreciate you a lot!

Thank you!

Comment: http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/

Comment: Wow thanks @User863 so much! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `atob` and `btoa` which uses base64 encoding and decoding.

```
<script>
    var scr = "function sample() {}";
    var jsCodeToEmbed = btoa(scr);
    var oScript = document.createElement("script");
    oScript.language = "javascript";
    oScript.type = "text/javascript";
    oScript.text = atob(jsCodeToEmbed);
    document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0).appendChild(oScript);
</script>
```

Comment: But yes this will use different encoding scheme than you had expected

Comment: Thank @SabaHassan ! I can use your suggestion and ddecode.com/hexdecoder to create 2 encryption layers. Have a nice day bro!